# Convergence of factor

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

In my math course there are some examples to test convergence of power-series with d'alembert.
One of the examples is :

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$

Now i tried to solve this with d'alembert.

$\lim_{n\to +\infty } \left| \frac{\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{x^n}{n!}}\right| \approx \lim_{n\to +\infty } \left|\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{x^n}\right| \approx \lim_{n\to +\infty } \left|\frac{x^n \times x}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{x^n}\right| \approx \lim_{n\to +\infty } \left|\frac{x}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{1}\right| \approx +\infty$

which makes it always **divergent**.

But the problem is that when checking my outcome using mathematica it said i should have always **convergent**. I double checked with the wolfram alpha widget and not suprisingly it also came up with **convergent**

[image: double check with wolfram alpha widget]

Could you figure out where i went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a simple mistake in the last step of the limit calculation, where you forgot that $\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}=\frac{n!}{n!\cdot (n+1)}$, meaning that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n!}{(n+1)!}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}\neq \infty.$$

Comment: oh snap i completely see where i went wrong forgot it was $n\to +\infty$

Comment: @RubenDefour Happens all the time. Don't worry. If you find this answer useful, don't forget to upvote it.

Comment: @RubenDefour Also, the sum is not only convergent, it also converges to $e^x$ and is perhaps the most famous of infinite sums.